# How to fetch data from google api token?

Tags: c#, google-api, access-token

I want to use Google Login Credentials in my website.So i am using Google API. I get a google API token in URL. So i want to get Login User data? I am using C#.
I got this URL after successfully Login and redirect back in My website:-

http://localhost:20885/WebServices/Welcome.aspx#state=/profile&access_token=ya29.AHES6ZRERYieYZIclNxQp3cPeXDnNWMP4IQuhDaj-TO_4wX2eqziRg&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600

Please Help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this .Net library

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

This will do all the heavy OpenID/OAuth work for you. You just need to point it at Google's OpenID URL.

Requesting specific user data, such as email, is easy and explained here:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Comment: Hello Sir
First of all Thank You very much for Response Me.
Actually i am using only Google ID not Open ID. 
And I want to know how we redirect the user on Gmail and redirect  back it on our web application and how we get login user data.Like First Name , Last Name,Email id , ID etc.
Thanks Again for responding.

Comment: The Google ID is an implementation of OpenID. When you connect to Stack Overflow using your GMail account, you get to sign in with your Google ID and then you get directed back to Stack Overflow. Is this what you're trying to implement?

Comment: Yes Sir,
And trying to get User Basic info like ID,FName,LName ,Email,UserName
etc. I am using .net framework.Please Help me and answer ASAP.. Thanks for response.

Comment: Look at this article by Rick Strahl - http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Sep/17/Integrating-OpenID-in-an-ASPNET-MVC-Application-using-DotNetOpenAuth - you should be able to adapt this to use the Google OpenID.

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript in your .aspx page:

```
// First, parse the query string
var params = {}, queryString = location.hash.substring(1),
regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;
while (m = regex.exec(queryString)) {
  params[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
}

// And send the token over to the server
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
// consider using POST so query isn't logged
req.open('GET', 'http://' + window.location.host + '/public/Google.aspx?' + queryString, true);

req.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    if (req.status == 200) {
      window.location = params['state']
    }
    else if (req.status == 400) {
      alert('There was an error processing the token.')
    }
    else {
      alert('something else other than 200 was returned')
    }
  }
};
req.send(null);
```

Use it to call your the same or another .aspx page.